# Apache httpd client certiifcate authorization issue

Tags: ssl, httpd.conf

**Short question**

How will Authorization work when Authentication is done with client certificates on Apache Server httpd?

**I know what I need, but I'm not sure that my question is clear. So I will explain in more details below**

I'm building a Subversion repository with Apache Server httpd on Ubuntu 22.04 and I need to establish 2 possible cases for users to able to log in. Basic Auth OR client certificate. I'm experiencing an issue with Authorization during client certificate authentication. It ignores assigned permissions and always has Read+Write access.

Scenarios:

It always has to be HTTPS

1. If a user doesn't have a certificate on their machine, they will log in with Basic Authentication and Authorization through HTTPS(It works fine)
2. If a user is working on a machine with a signed certificate, there is no need to submit credentials to log in. Just open the page in e.g. WebBrowser(It works only partially fine. Explaining below)

To be able to make sure that client cert Authn and Authz work correctly, I created 2 client certificates and signed them with Self-signed CA.
I added lines in the authorization file under the directive `AuthzSVNAccessFile`  It is supposed that one of them has Read+Write permissions and another one doesn't.

```
[aliases]
testuser_cert_subject1 = C = PL, ST = TestST, L = TestL, O = TestInc., OU = TestOU, CN = Test Test
testuser_cert_subject2 = C = PL, ST = TestST2, L = TestL2, O = TestInc.2, OU = TestOU2, CN = Test2 Test2
[/]
testuser_cert_subject1 = rw
testuser_cert_subject2 =
```

Both certificates will give Read+Write permisisons for a user(assigned restriction in authorization.txt doesn't work for client certificates).
Please see my httpd.conf below(I skipped a few directive. I believe they are not critical here)

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"

Listen 443

DBDriver sqlite3
DBDParams "/home/testuser/UsersAuthenticationProviderApacheHttpd.db"
DBDMin  4
DBDKeep 8
DBDMax  20
DBDExptime 300
DBDPersist On

SSLCACertificateFile "/home/testuser/Documents/cacerts/CA/cacert.pem"
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl_scache(512000)"

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName local.suregames
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/home/testuser/Documents/cacerts/server/servercert.pem"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/testuser/Documents/cacerts/server/serverkey.pem"
    # require a client certificate which has to be directly
    # signed by our CA certificate in ca.crt
    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLVerifyDepth 1

</VirtualHost>

<Directory "/home/testuser/.svnrepos/FirstGameRepo">
    DavGenericLockDB /usr/local/apache2/var/DavLock
    DavMinTimeout 600
</Directory>

<Location />
    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath On
    SVNPath /home/testuser/.svnrepos/FirstGameRepo
    #SVNParentPath /home/testuser/.svnrepos
    
    SVNActivitiesDB "/home/testuser/.svnrepos/FirstGameRepo/dav"
    SVNAllowBulkUpdates Off
    SVNCacheFullTexts On
    SVNCacheTextDeltas On
    
    SVNPathAuthz On
    SVNReposName Games
    
    Require ssl-verify-client
    
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName DAV/home/testuser/.svnrepos
    AuthBasicProvider socache dbd
    #AuthUserFile "/usr/local/apache2/passwd/passwords"
    # Also required for caching: tell the cache to cache dbd lookups!
    AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
    AuthnCacheContext my-server
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT password FROM authn WHERE user = %s"

    AuthzForceUsernameCase Lower
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /usr/local/apache2/passwd/authorization.txt
    AuthzSVNAnonymous Off
    
    
    Require valid-user
</Location>
```